# Shortest path with a twist

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have `n` vertices and `m` undirected weighted edges between them (weights are representing minutes). Each vertex contains a number of minutes required to drink a coffee on that vertex.

I want to determine the shortest amount of time (minutes) neccessary to get from vertex `v` to vertex `w` but with the additional constraint that I have to drink my coffee on exactly one of the vertices on my way from `v` to `w`).

**Example**:

(number in the vertex is the amount of minutes required to drink a coffee, the weights on the edges represent the amount of minutes neccessary to travel this edge)

Get from `v` to `w` and drink a coffe on your way, output the minimal neccessary time (output should be 30).

[image]

**My current approach** is to find the shortest path with Dijkstra (sum up the weights of all edges on that path) and then add the value of the vertex with the lowest coffee time on that path to my result in order to get the total amount of time neccessary to get from `v` to `w`.

My approach doesn't work, here is an example where my approach fails (the result of my approach is 12 minutes, the actual result should be 6 minutes) :

[image: Counterexample for my approach]

How to determine the shortest amount of time from vertex `v` to `w` with the constraint that I need to drink a coffe on my path?

Comment: This seems like a question for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's a question I received during a programming interview.

Comment: It's best to state that within the question but I still believe that this would be better on the math exchange.

Comment: Is the vertex with "9" even connected to the graph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to solve this problem is:

1. make 2 copies of your graph -- the `need_coffee` version and the `had_coffee version`.
2. Connect each `need_coffee` node with the corresponding `had_coffee` node, with an edge cost equal to the cost of drinking coffee at that node.
3. Use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path from `V_need_coffee` to `W_had_coffee`

Comment: Does this problem have a name?  Where can I learn more about it and maybe find a more detailed description of this standard way of solving it?

Comment: It's not just this problem, but lots of similar problems where you have to find a shortest path along with other criteria.  I've heard the technique called 'graph layering', but I don't know if there's a standard name for it.  Here's a good talk about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ5jsbhAv_M&feature=youtu.be&t=47m7s

Comment: Your algorithms solutions are always so insightful

Comment: This solution is elegant, straightforward and works for me, I just don't understand the connection between your approach for solving this problem and the video you referenced?

Comment: The video shows using the same technique for "shortest path with <= N hops".  It also works for shortest path with alternating red+blue edges, shortest path with at most N special edges, etc., etc.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot from your solution. Would upvote twice if I could.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to write an A* algorithm to solve this. When you expand a node, you will get two children for every outgoing vertex; one where you drink the coffee and one where you don't. If you precondition your algorithm with a run of Dijkstra's (so you already have precomputed shortest paths), then you could inform the A* search's heuristic with the Dijkstra's shortest path + minimum time to drink a coffee (or + 0 if coffee already drunk).

The A* search terminates (you've reached your goal) when you have not only arrived at the destination node, but also have drank your coffee.

Example search for second scenario:

```
Want: A --> C

A(10) -- 1 -- B(10) -- 1 -- C(10)
 \                           /
  \                         /
   2 -------- D(2) ------- 2   



Expand A
  A*(cost so far: 10, heuristic: 2)          total est cost: 12
  B (cost so far: 1, heuristic: 1 + 2)       total est cost: 3
  B*(cost so far: 11, heuristic: 1)          total est cost: 12
  D (cost so far: 2, heuristic: 2 + 2)       total est cost: 6
  D*(cost so far: 14, heuristic: 2)          total est cost: 16
  Expand B
    A*(cost so far: 12, heuristic: 2)        total est cost: 14
    B*(cost so far: 11, heuristic: 1)        total est cost: 12
    C(cost so far: 2, heuristic: 2)          total est cost: 4
    C*(cost so far: 12, heuristic: 0)        total est cost: 12
    Expand C
      B*(cost so far: 13, heuristic: 1)      total est cost: 14
      C*(cost so far: 12, heuristic: 0)      total est cost: 12
  Expand D
    A* (cost so far: 14, heuristic: 2)       total est cost: 16
    D* (cost so far: 4, heuristic: 2)        total est cost: 6
    C  (cost so far: 4, heuristic: 0 + 2)    total est cost: 6
    C* (cost so far: 6, heuristic: 0)        total est cost: 6
    Expand C*
       goal reached.                         total cost: 6

Key:
  * = Coffee from parent was drunk
```

So you can see that what this algorithm will do is first try to go down Dijkstra's shortest path (never drinking the coffee). And then when it reaches the end it will see a physical goal state, but with a need to still drink a coffee. When it expands this physical goal state to drink coffee, it will see that the cost to arrive is suboptimal, so it continues its search from another branch and proceeds.

Note that in the above, A and A* are different nodes, so in some way you can revisit a parent node (but only if the coffee drinking state is different).
This is to address a graph like this:

```
Want A-->B

A(20) -- 1 -- B(20)
  \
   2
    \
    C(1)
```

Where it would make sense to go from A->C->C*->A*->B*

I'm not sure yet if we need to distinguish "coffee drank" states by which node we drank the coffee at, but I'm leaning towards no.

Comment: Interesting approach, looks fine (I can't come up with a counterexample).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is as following:

1. Compute the shortest path from u to all the other vertices and call it p(u,x)
2. Compute the shortest path from all the vertices to v and call it p(x,v)
3. loop over all vertices and find the minimum of the value (p(u,x)+coffee(x)+p(x,v))

Doing so will lead to an algorithm with the same time complexity than Dijkstra's one (if you use Dijkstra's algorithm in step 1 and 2)

Comment: You approach runs Dijkstra (O(E * logV)) 2 times for each node, shouldn't the complexity be O(V * E * logV)?

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is able to compute the shortest path from one node to all the other ones, see the wikipage for example

Comment: to be more precise, you can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Single-source_shortest_paths

Comment: So in step 1. your algorithm runs Dijkstra once (determines the shortest path from u to all other vertices) and in step 2. you run Dijkstra to determine the shortest path from v to all other vertices. In step 3. you iterate through all nodes and calculate p(u,x)+coffee(x)+p(x,v), save the minimum and output it at the end. Overall this runs Dijkstra 2 times and iterates through all the nodes once. Did I get that correctly?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it !